# How do I add this in the autorun.iss

Tags: inno-setup, autorun

I have this scrip, and i want agregate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsrpg.png

a.flags pictures for change the language with the autorun

b.Play sound with mouse on button

c.desciption label

**AUTORUN.iss**

```
[CustomMessages]
#ifdef English
en.Aplay=&Play
en.Ainstall=&Install
en.AUnistall=&Uninstall
en.Aexit=&Exit
en.ABrowse=&Browse DVD
en.AWebsite=&Website
#endif

#ifdef Italian
it.Aplay=&Gioca
it.AInstall=&Installa
it.AUnistall=&Disinstalla
it.Aexit=&Esci
it.ABrowse=&Sfoglia DVD
it.AWebsite=&Website
#endif

#ifdef Spanish
es.Aplay=&Jugar
es.AInstall=&Instalar
es.AUnistall=&Desinstalar
es.Aexit=&Salir
es.ABrowse=&Explorar DVD
es.AWebsite=&Website
#endif

#ifdef German
de.Aplay=&Spielen
de.AInstall=&Install...
de.AUnistall=&Deinstallieren
de.Aexit=&Ausfahrt
de.ABrowse=S&töbern DVD
de.AWebsite=&Webseite
#endif

#ifdef French
fr.Aplay=&Jouer
fr.AInstall=&Installer
fr.AUnistall=&Désinstaller
fr.Aexit=&Sortie
fr.ABrowse=&Parcourir les DVD
fr.AWebsite=&Website
#endif

#ifdef Russian
ru.Aplay=&Play
ru.Ainstall=&Install
ru.AUnistall=&Uninstall
ru.Aexit=&Exit
ru.ABrowse=&Browse DVD
ru.AWebsite=&Website
#endif

#ifdef Czech
cz.Aplay=&Prehrát 
cz.AInstall=&Instalovat 
cz.AUnistall=&Odinstalovat 
cz.Aexit=&Vypadni 
cz.ABrowse=&Procházet DVD 
cz.AWebsite=&Webové stránky
#endif

#ifdef Polish
pl.Aplay=&Odtwórz 
pl.AInstall=&Zainstaluj 
pl.AUnistall=&Odinstaluj 
pl.Aexit=&Wynos 
pl.ABrowse=&Przegladaj  DVD
pl.AWebsite=&Stronie internetowej
#endif

#ifdef Dutch
nl.Aplay=&Speel 
nl.AInstall=&Installeer 
nl.AUnistall=&Uninstall 
nl.Aexit=&Uitstappen 
nl.ABrowse=&Bladeren  DVD
nl.AWebsite=&Website van
#endif

#ifdef BrazilianPortuguese
porbr.Aplay=&Jogue 
porbr.AInstall=&Instalar
porbr.AUnistall=&Desinstalar
porbr.Aexit=&Saiam
porbr.ABrowse=&Navegar  DVD
porbr.AWebsite=&O site
#endif

[code]
var HForm: TSetupForm;
    AbgImage : TBitmapImage;
    #ifdef AutorunStandardButtons
    Button1,Button2,Button3: TNewButton;
    #endif
    #ifdef AutorunLabelButtons
    ButtonLabel1,ButtonLabel2,ButtonLabel3,ButtonLabel4,ButtonLabel5,LabelMouse : TLabel;
    ButtonsLabelShadow: array [1..5] of TLabel;
    #endif
    #ifdef AMusicLoop
    MLabel : TLabel;
    MPanel: Tpanel;
    MBitmap : TBitmapImage;
    #endif
    MCIstr: PChar;
    Install: Boolean;
    mute: byte;

const
    AWidth= 704; //cambio
    AHeight= 372;//cambio
    SND_OPT= $1;
    OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize= 17; //cambio
    OnMouseOverALabelButtonsFontSize= 20; //cambio
    AFontName= '{#FontName}'; 

    LabelButton1Top= 300; //cambio
    LabelButton1Left= 25; //cambio

    LabelButton2Top= 300; //cambio
    LabelButton2Left= 125; //cambio

    LabelButton3Top= 300; //cambio
    LabelButton3Left= 225; //cambio

    LabelButton4Top= 300; //cambio
    LabelButton4Left= 325; //cambio

    LabelButton5Top= 260; //cambio
    LabelButton5Left= 560; //cambio

#ifdef AutorunLabelButtons
procedure ButtonLabelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
TLabel(sender).Font.Size:=OnMouseOverALabelButtonsFontSize;  
TLabel(sender).Font.Color:=ClRed; //cambio
ButtonsLabelShadow[TLabel(Sender).Tag].Font.Size:= OnMouseOverALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

procedure LabelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
ButtonLabel1.Font.Size:=OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonsLabelShadow[1].Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel1.Font.Color:= ClWhite; //cambio
ButtonLabel2.Font.Size:=OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonsLabelShadow[2].Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel2.Font.Color:= ClWhite;//cambio
ButtonLabel3.Font.Size:=OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonsLabelShadow[3].Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel3.Font.Color:= ClWhite; //cambio
ButtonLabel4.Font.Size:=OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel4.Font.Color:= ClWhite; //cambio
ButtonsLabelShadow[4].Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel5.Font.Size:=OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
ButtonLabel5.Font.Color:= ClWhite; //cambio
ButtonsLabelShadow[5].Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

procedure BrowseLabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{src}'),
     '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode); 
end;


procedure PILabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
Var ResultCode: integer;
    appath: string;

begin
 PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
 if TLabel(sender).caption=ExpandConstant('{cm:AInstall}') then begin
 HForm.Close
 Install:=True;
 end else begin
 RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}', 
     '{#Entry}', appath)
 if not Exec(appath+'\{#Exepath}', '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewNoWait, ResultCode) then MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode)+': {#Exename}', mbCriticalError, MB_OK)
     else begin
 HForm.Close;
 Install:=False;
 end;
 end;
end;

procedure UnInstLabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
Var ResultCode: integer;
    appath: string;
begin
PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}',
     '{#Entry}', appath)
     Exec((appath +'\unins000.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
      ewNoWait, ResultCode)
HForm.Close
Install:=False;
end;

procedure ExitLabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
 PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
 HForm.Close
 Install:=False;
end;

procedure WebLabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;

begin
  PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
  shellexec('open', 'http://fileforums.com', '', '',SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewnowait, ResultCode) //cambio
  Install:=False;
end;

#endif

#ifdef AutorunStandardButtons
procedure PIButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
Var ResultCode: integer;
    appath: string;

begin
 PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
 if TNewButton(sender).caption=ExpandConstant('{cm:AInstall}') then begin
 HForm.Close
 Install:=True;
 end else begin
 RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}',
     '{#Entry}', appath)
 if not Exec(appath+'\{#Exepath}', '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewNoWait, ResultCode) then MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode)+': {#Exename}', mbCriticalError, MB_OK)
     else begin
 HForm.Close;
 Install:=False;
 end;
 end;
end;

procedure ExitButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
 PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
 HForm.Close
 Install:=False;
end;

procedure UnInstButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
Var ResultCode: integer;
    appath: string;
begin
PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}',
     '{#Entry}', appath)
     Exec((appath +'\unins000.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
      ewNoWait, ResultCode)
HForm.Close
Install:=False;
end;
#endif

#ifdef AMusicLoop
procedure MLabelOnClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
      PlaySound(expandConstant('{tmp}\Click.wav'),0,SND_OPT);
Case mute of
      0: begin
      mciSendString('PAUSE AMusicLoop', MCIstr, 255, 0);
      MBitmap.Left:=ScaleX(-23);
      mute:=1;
      end;
      1: begin
      mciSendString('PLAY AMusicLoop REPEAT', MCIstr, 255, 0);
      MBitmap.Left:=0;
      mute:=0;
      end;
end;
end;
#endif

function LaunchAutorun: Boolean;

begin
#ifdef AMusicLoop
ExtractTemporaryFile('{#Autorunmp3filename}');
ExtractTemporaryFile('mute_on_off.bmp');
#endif
ExtractTemporaryFile('{#ClickSoundfilename}');
ExtractTemporaryFile('AutorunBGI.BMP');
HForm:=CreateCustomForm;

With HForm Do
Begin
ClientWidth:=AWidth;
ClientHeight:=AHeight;
Position := poScreenCenter;
BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AppName} - Autorun');
end;

AbgImage:=TBitmapImage.Create(HForm);
With AbgImage Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Align:=alClient;
Stretch:=True;
end;
AbgImage.bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AutorunBGI.BMP'));

#ifdef AutorunLabelButtons
LabelMouse:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With LabelMouse Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Width:=HForm.Width;
Height:=HForm.Height;
Caption:='';
OnMouseMove := @LabelMouseMove;
end;
#endif

#ifdef AutorunStandardButtons
Button1:=TNewButton.Create(HForm);
With Button1 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Left:= 150;
Top:=279;
Cursor:=crHand;
OnClick := @PIButtonOnClick;
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}') then Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:APlay}') else Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AInstall}');
end;

Button2:=TNewButton.Create(HForm);
With Button2 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AUnistall}');
Left:=249;
Top:=Button1.Top;
Cursor:=crHand;
OnClick := @UnInstButtonOnClick;
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}') then Enabled:=True else Enabled:=False;
end;

Button3:=TNewButton.Create(HForm);
With Button3 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:Aexit}');
Left:=348;
Top:=Button1.Top;
Cursor:=crHand;
OnClick := @ExitButtonOnClick;
end;
#endif

#ifdef AMusicLoop
MPanel := TPanel.Create(HForm);
with MPanel do
begin
Left := 672;
Top := 9;
Width := 23;
Height := 23;
Caption := '';
Parent := HForm;
end;

MBitmap := TBitmapImage.Create(HForm);
with MBitmap do
begin

Parent := MPanel;
Left := ScaleX(0); //cambio
Top := ScaleY(0); //cambio
Width := ScaleX(46); //cambio
Height := ScaleY(23); //cambio
MBitmap.bitmap.loadfromfile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\mute_on_off.bmp'))
end;

MLabel:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With MLabel Do
Begin
Parent:=MPanel;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=0;
Top:=0;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
Width:=23;
Height:=23;
Autosize:=False;
Caption:='';
Font.Name:='Arial';
Font.Style:=[fsBold];
Font.Size:= 7;
Cursor:=crHand;
OnClick := @MLabelOnClick;
end;
mute:=0;
#endif

#ifdef AutorunLabelButtons
ButtonsLabelShadow[1]:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonsLabelShadow[1] Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton1Left+ScaleX(1);
Top:=LabelButton1Top+ScaleY(2);
Font.Color:=clBlack;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:='';
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}') then Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:APlay}') else Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AInstall}');
end;

ButtonLabel1:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonLabel1 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton1Left;
Top:=LabelButton1Top;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:='';
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
Cursor:=crHand;
Tag:=1;
OnClick := @PILabelOnClick;
OnMouseMove := @ButtonLabelMouseMove;
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}') then Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:APlay}') else Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AInstall}');
end;

ButtonsLabelShadow[2]:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonsLabelShadow[2] Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton2Left+ScaleY(1);
Top:=LabelButton2Top+ScaleY(2);
Font.Color:=clBlack;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AUnistall}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

ButtonLabel2:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonLabel2 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton2Left;
Top:=LabelButton2Top;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AUnistall}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
Cursor:=crHand;
Tag:=2;
OnClick := @UnInstLabelOnClick;
OnMouseMove := @ButtonLabelMouseMove;
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '{#RegEntry}') then Enabled:=True else Enabled:=False;
end;

ButtonsLabelShadow[3]:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonsLabelShadow[3] Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton3Left+ScaleY(1);
Top:=LabelButton3Top+ScaleY(2);
Font.Color:=clBlack;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:ABrowse}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

ButtonLabel3:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonLabel3 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton3Left;
Top:=LabelButton3Top;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:ABrowse}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
Cursor:=crHand;
Tag:=3;
OnClick := @BrowseLabelOnClick;;
OnMouseMove := @ButtonLabelMouseMove;
end;

ButtonsLabelShadow[4]:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonsLabelShadow[4] Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton4Left+ScaleY(1);
Top:=LabelButton4Top+ScaleY(2);
Font.Color:=clBlack;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:Aexit}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

ButtonLabel4:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonLabel4 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton4Left;
Top:=LabelButton4Top;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:Aexit}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
Cursor:=crHand;
Tag:=4;
OnClick := @ExitLabelOnClick;
OnMouseMove := @ButtonLabelMouseMove;
end;

ButtonsLabelShadow[5]:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonsLabelShadow[5] Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton5Left+ScaleY(1);
Top:=LabelButton5Top+ScaleY(2);
Font.Color:=clBlack;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AWebsite}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
end;

ButtonLabel5:=TLabel.Create(HForm);
With ButtonLabel5 Do
Begin
Parent:=HForm;
Transparent:=True;
Left:=LabelButton5Left;
Top:=LabelButton5Top;
Font.Color:=ClWhite;
AutoSize:=True;
Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AWebsite}');
Font.Name:=AFontName;
Font.Style:=[];
Font.Size:= OnMouseOutALabelButtonsFontSize;
Cursor:=crHand;
Tag:=5;
OnClick := @WebLabelOnClick;
OnMouseMove := @ButtonLabelMouseMove;
end;


#endif

#ifdef AMusicLoop
mciSendString('OPEN ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\{#Autorunmp3filename} TYPE MPEGVIDEO ALIAS AMusicLoop', MCIstr, 255, 0);
mciSendString('PLAY AMusicLoop REPEAT', MCIstr, 255, 0);
#endif
HForm.ShowModal;
#ifdef AMusicLoop
mciSendString('STOP AMusicLoop', MCIstr, 255, 0);
#endif
HForm.Free;
Result:=Install;
end;
```

The scrip is formed by tho scrips: Autorun.iss and the base.iss

Comment: a) use `TBitmapImage` with binded `OnClick` event in which you'll update all the needed component captions. b) bind `OnClick` event to the button of your choice and play sound the same way as you do. c) don't get it.

Comment: There are autorun tools that are far better suited to your requirements that trying to twist Inno Setup into an auto run tool.